# Join on two associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 4 models: `Catalog`, `Product`, `Value`, and `Characteristic`.
A catalog has many products, a product has many values, and a value belongs to a characteristic and belongs to a product.

Thus:

- a product has a `catalog_id`
- a value has a `product_id` and a `characteristic_id`
- a characteristic doens't have any foreign key linking to those models
- a characteristic has many values

I want to find the characteristics for the values of a given products collection belonging to a catalog without loading all the products and all the values.

What I could do but seems highly inefficient:

```
@products = Product.where(catalog_id: @catalog.id)
@characteristics = Value.distinct.where(value_id: @products.pluck(:id)).pluck(:characteristic_id)
```

Here is what I've tried:

```
Characteristic.joins(value: :product).where(values:{products:{catalog_id: @catalog.id}})
```

But I get this error:

```
Can't join 'Characteristic' to association named 'value'; perhaps you misspelled it?
```

Where did I miss something ?

Comment: What does `Characterictic` model code look like?

Comment: @MarekLipka the `Characteristic` table doens't have any foreign key linking to these models. A value is basically between a product and a characteristic. It has a foreign key to both models. Value has a product_id and characteristic_id

Comment: That means `Characteristic` has many `values`, right? If so, you indeed mispelled the association name, cause it should be `Characteristic.joins(values: :product)`.

Comment: Hmm indeed you're right, my bad, `Characteristic` has many `values`. I still don't get how I can join it though

Comment: @MarekLipka i've added this to the questions thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what you wrote in the question, the `Characteristic` model is linked with `has_many` association with `Value`. So you can perform joining this way:

```
Characteristic.joins(values: :product).where(products: { catalog_id: @catalog.id })
```

Note that you're not supposed to nest `products` in `where` clause, since it's 'regular' condition on `products` table.

Comment: thanks for your answer! How should I avoid the nesting ?

Comment: @GrahamSlick what nesting? You mean `values: :product`? Why do you want to avoid this, if so?